# Why are Synchronization Token and Cookie-to-Header patterns un-natural for Web APIs?

Tags: oauth, csrf, api, openid-connect

I have heard that CSRF prevention techniques are not natural for Web APIs.

For instance, we might have a client application at domainA that implements both [the Synchronization Token Pattern and the Cookie-to-Header pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery#Prevention). When the client POSTs to the resource server at domainB, the resource server needs to validate those security values, and since the resource server would not know what synchronization token value nor what cookie-to-header value to expect, it will have a hard time validating those.

That being said, the resource server could validate the synchronization token and/or the cookie-to-header value using the same technique that it uses to validate the access token. Given that, why are those two techniques considered inappropriate for a Web API?

Comment: The question in the final paragraph does not reflect that in the title. Could you edit?

Comment: @billc.cn Done.

Comment: Generally (though not necessarily), these techniques require server state.  Most APIs are now based on REST principles, one of which is that the server should be stateless.  I suspect that is the objection.

Comment: @crovers Doesn't the validation of an access token also rely on server state? And if it doesn't, then why do the CSRF techniques need to rely on server state?

Comment: @ShaunLuttin Access tokens MAY require server state - and if they do, they are a place where people are willing to bend a bit (or direct to a separate server that does hold state).  If there are shared secrets between all servers, though, you can do CSRF tokens that don't require state - I don't see an objection to those.

Comment: @crovers Are people willing to bend more for access tokens then they are willing to bend for CSRF tokens? If so, why? This gets to the crux of my question.

Answer (score 1):

In a Web CSRF flow, the server sends the token as part of the response that serves the webpage, so the token is delivered "for free". Typically, the same server is also the target for those POST requests so it can easily validate the tokens.

When you call a Web API, the target is probably a different server so the token will either have to be communicated out-of-band or the client will have to send a request just for the token to use in a subsequent request. In either cases, the Web API server handles double the number of requests, which is wasteful.

Good alternatives are digital signature schemes or HTTP methods/headers not allowed by browsers.

Comment: This makes sense. What it leaves out, though, is why the delivery/validation of a CSRF token is not appropriate whereas the delivery/validation of an access token is appropriate.

Comment: Could you clarify what do you mean by "access token"? Are these OAuth tokens?

Comment: Yes. These are OAuth tokens.

Comment: In the case of OAuth tokens, they are designed to be requested once and reused for many resource requests. You also normally get them from yet another server so no way to save that request. They can replace CSRF tokens in some cases.

Comment: Yes. I understand that too. What I am trying to get at, is why are access tokens a viable replacement for CSRF tokens. It seems like the problems with CSRF tokens should also be problems with access tokens. You *might* have answered this in your last comment, when you mentioned that access tokens are for many requests... are CSRF tokens per request? That would indeed lead to a lot more overhead!

Comment: Access tokens can normally serve as CSRF tokens because they cannot be obtained by a CSRForger under same origin policy (same idea behind CSRF tokens). As for CSRF tokens, no standard exists, so there are all kinds of implementations. Many web API clients are also stateless so they cannot easily keep a session-based CSRF token around.

Comment: I'm afraid neither the answer nor the comments address why access tokens are appropriate for Web APIs but CSRF tokens are not. Regarding your last comment, if an API client cannot easily keep a session-based CSRF token around, then it would not be able to keep an access token around either.